# If $f'(a) = 0$ then there exist some $\delta$ such that $f$ is monotone in $(a,a+\delta)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'(a) = 0$, then there exists some $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is monotone on $(a,a+\delta )$.

If $f'$ is continuous, this is true, but I'm not sure about it if $f'$ is discontinuous.

Comment: what do you mean by $f$ discontinuous? If $f$ is differentiable it is continuous.

Comment: @C.Zhihao: The O.P. wrote ‘$f\mkern1mu\color{red}'$ discontinuous’.

Comment: Take $a=0$, $b=\pi$ and $f(x)=x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$. All premises are satisfied, but the conclusion isn't. I strongly suspect there is a typo and the condition should be $f'(a)\ne 0$.

Comment: No, it's  not true even if $f'$ is continuous; the answer below is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, even with the hypothesis  ‘$f'$ continuous’. As counter-example, consider the function  defined as
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin\dfrac1{x},&\text{if }\; x\ne 0\\[0.5ex]f(0)=0.\end{cases}$$
It is continuous on $\mathbf R$, so the function
$$f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t$$
is differentiable for all $x$, by the *First fundamental theorem* of Integral Calculus, and its derivative is equal to
$$f'(x)=x\sin\frac1x\;\text{if }x\ne 0,\quad f'(0)=0.$$
However, $f'(x)$ doesn't have a constant sign in any neighbourhood of $0$ since $\;\smash{\dfrac1x}$ tends to $\infty$ when $x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Either positive or negative. It's the standard criterion for monotonicity.

Comment: ??? In fact $f'$ is continuous in this example!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You're right. Actually I began with another example in mind, and forgot to change the introductory sentence. Thanks for pointing the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The original statement is false even supposing $f'$ is continuous. There must be a typo; surely we're supposed to assume that $f'(a)\ne0$.

If $f'(a)\ne0$ and $f'$ is continuous then it's trivial that $f$ is monotone in some interval about $a$ (if say $f'(a)>0$ then $f'>0$ near $a$).

We finally answer the question the OP meant to ask: Supposing just that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(a)\ne0$ does not imply that $f$ is monotone in any neighborhood of $a$.

Let $$g(t)=\begin{cases}
t^2\sin(1/t^2),&(t\ne0),
\\0,&(t=0).\end{cases}$$Let $$f(t)=t+g(t).$$
Then $f$ is differentiable, $f'(0)=1$, but since $f'(t)=1-\frac 2t\cos(1/t^2)+2t\sin(1/t^2)$ for $t\ne0$ there is no neighborhood of $0$ in which $f$ is monotone.